# Запуск программы начиная со 2 формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Как переиначить проект, чтобы при старте программы изначально запускалась вторая форма вместо первой. Я не хочу вызвать вторую из первой и первую из второй, будьте внимательны!

Comment: Поменяйте формы местами. Чем такой вариант не подходит?

Comment: @Kromster как именно поменять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы форму отобразить, нужно сначала создать ее экземпляр. Вам нужно найти это место, где создается экземпляр формы и внести корректировки в него. В Windows Forms проекте это место - класс Program.

Откройте файл Program.cs и увидите примерно это:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на последнюю строчку метода Main, именно в ней создается экземпляр Form1, отредактируйте это место.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)